# dictation for voice memos

Tags: ios, voice-dictation

The built in Dictation on the iOS keyboard works like a charm.

But how in the world can I use it to transcribe an existing recording (in Voice Memos)?

If that's not possible, what combination of apps (or even web apps) could perform transcription of audio recordings in Some recording app (I don't mind using a different recording app if it somehow lets me transcribe)?

I see two or three transcription apps on the App Store but they all want a high per-minute fee for presumably human transcription. Machine transcription (especially Apples high-quality Dictation feature) is good enough for me.

Comment: I'd try playing it back from your computer & hold your phone up to the speaker.

Comment: Good answer but I'd be surprised if there isn't a way to do this with just an iphone.